# How to call a method once the MKMapView delegate methods completed

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am implementing a MKMapView based application. In that I need to call a method once the pins are displayed. Is there a method to know the delegate methods are completed and we can make our calls?, can you guys please suggest me on this?

Thanks in Advance,
Sekhar Bethalam.

Answer (score 0):

Try this delegate method :

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
```